# How to write a simple Axis client (service generated from netbeans)

Tags: netbeans, client, service

This is really basic, but here goes:

I have created a simple "hello world" client using net beans, and I can successfully "test" it by right-clicking and saying "test in browser".

However, the tutorial doesn't go any further - specifically, it doesn't give the actual client code for invoking the service.

Can anyone point out to some example code for this?

Thanks,
Jack

Answer (score 0):

Here it is - on the netbeans ide: new file, web services, web service client